# C++ Error when I call a parent method as a derived object

Tags: c++, methods, parent, derived

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class parent
{
    int x=0;
    public:
    int getx()
    {
        return x;
    }
};

class child : public parent
{
    int x=7;
};
int main()
{
  parent cat;
  cout << cat.getx();
  child s;
  cout << s.getx();    //stops working here
  return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of the issue I am having. Why doesn't it print 7 when i call cout << getx() as a derived object?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question until you post your code for `Stack` and `LinkedList` and what you mean by "stops working."

Comment: I edited the post, displaying an example that is very similar to the problem that I am currently having.

Comment: Seems to work OK for me - [demo](https://ideone.com/TMUSfv)

Comment: Much better! I don't have an answer for you right now but I'm sure someone else will pick this up.

Comment: What do you mean "stops working"?

Comment: i am such an idiot. can you guys give it a look again, I made some changes

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class parent
{
protected:
    int m_x;
public:
    parent(int x = 0) : m_x(x) {}
    int getx(){return m_x;}
};
class child : public parent
{
public:
    child():parent(7){}
};
int main()
{
  parent cat;
  std::cout << cat.getx() << std::endl;

  child s;
  std::cout << s.getx() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Result

```
dgs@dhome:~/Develop/Test2$ make getx
g++     getx.cpp   -o getx
dgs@dhome:~/Develop/Test2$ ./getx
0
7
```